# Using MXXMLWriter to output an XML document into a string

Tags: visual-c++, atl, msxml

I'm trying to output a formatted XML document from a DOM object into a string, as shown in the code below. The thing is, while the dom->get_xml() method does return a value, the MXXMLWriter->output does not, as you can see on the screenshot. All method calls return S_OK. What could be the issue here?

Here's my code:

```
CComPtr<IMXWriter> w;
HRESULT hr;
hr = w.CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(MXXMLWriter), NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER);

hr = w->put_indent(VARIANT_TRUE);

CComPtr<ISAXXMLReader> rd;
hr = rd.CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(SAXXMLReader60), NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER);

CComPtr<ISAXContentHandler> hc;
hr = w.QueryInterface<ISAXContentHandler>(&hc);
CComPtr<ISAXErrorHandler> he;
hr = w.QueryInterface<ISAXErrorHandler>(&he);
CComPtr<ISAXDTDHandler> hd;
hr = w.QueryInterface<ISAXDTDHandler>(&hd);

hr = rd->putContentHandler(hc);
hr = rd->putErrorHandler(he);
hr = rd->putDTDHandler(hd);
hr = rd->putProperty(L"http://xml.org/sax/properties/lexical-handler", CComVariant(w));
hr = rd->putProperty(L"http://xml.org/sax/properties/declaration-handler", CComVariant(w));

BSTR body = ::SysAllocStringLen(NULL, 1024);
ZeroMemory(body, 1024 * sizeof(OLECHAR));
CComVariant out(body);
w->put_encoding(CComBSTR(L"utf-8"));
hr = w->put_output(out);
hr = rd->parse(CComVariant(dom));

dom->get_xml(&xmlStr);

return std::wstring(xmlStr);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation states that

Output can be:

> - Any implementation of the IStream interface. (The resulting document will be written into the provided IStream).
> - A string.
> - A DOMDocument object.
>
> For more information about setting the output property to a DOMDocument object, see Create a DOMDocument Object from SAX Events.
>
> Setting this property to the empty value (VT_EMPTY or " ") will return output to the internal string and reset it

You apparently want the writer to fill the string. So it is suggested to use an empty string to instruct writer to fill its internal buffer and then you can obtain it via property getter.

You instead attempt to provide your own buffer to be filled, and this is the advertised behavior of the writer.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I have the same problem, but I'm not getting which object needs to "use an empty string to instruct the writer"

Comment: @stu: you provide an argument which is a variant with an empty string inside. Please start a new question and provide your code snippet which does not work, if this documentation excerpt is not helpful.